# Trouble querying results from three tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to query some data to practice and these are the three tables:

```
course    assignment    assignment_submissions
id        id            id
          course        assignment
```

As you can see the relationships are pretty basic, but I'm just that rusty with plain SQL, that's why I'm practicing.

Given a `course 'id'`, how can I find all the `assignment_submission` rows that belong to it?

I would need to get the assignments, then for each assignment get each submissions. Here's my attempt, but this fails and returns a MUCH larger dataset than expected.

```
SELECT sub.id, sub.grade,
FROM uv_assignment_submissions sub, uv_assignment ass
WHERE ass.course = 1245
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need a `JOIN` all 3 tables, `course`, `assignment` and `assignment_submissions`. I have used a `JOIN` construct assuming you need to display the course details only when some records exists for `assignments` and `assignment_submissions`.

The reason why your query fails is because, its currently getting the `Cartesian` product of all records from the `2 tables`, you would need a condition to specify which rows are valid for the current `assignment` by specifying a `JOIN` condition

Something like this should work

```
SELECT
  c.id,
  asub.id
FROM
  course c
  JOIN assignment a ON ( c.id = a.course )
  JOIN assignment_submissions asub ON ( asub.ID = a.assignment )
WHERE
  c.id = 10 --your course id goes here OR c.id in (10, 20, 30) -- for multiple IDS
```

More on SQL Joins: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON ( as.assignment = a.id ) WHERE c.id = 1245'

Comment: Try now, I overlooked, `as` is a keyword in MYSQL, its better to use a unique identifier for the table alias instead, try the updated query

Comment: Thanks! This worked fine. SQL seems like a very powerful tool!

Comment: @gillyspy this is what happens when I race :D

Answer (score 3):

the problem with your attempt is that you have a cross product of the three tables and are only limiting which rows in uv_assignment are used.  So for course 1245 you are showing every assignment even if not relevant to that course, and so on.

However, you were close:

```
SELECT sub.id, sub.grade,
FROM 
    uv_assignment_submissions sub, uv_assignment ass
WHERE 
    sub.assignment = ass.id
    and ass.course = course.id
    and ass.course = 1245
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.ID AS Course
     , a.id AS Assignment
     , `as`.id AS Assignment_sub
  FROM course c
  JOIN assignment a 
       ON c.id = a.course
  JOIN assignment_submissions `as` 
       ON a.id = `as`.assignment
 WHERE c.id = 1
```

Output:

```
╔════════╦════════════╦════════════════╗
║ COURSE ║ ASSIGNMENT ║ ASSIGNMENT_SUB ║
╠════════╬════════════╬════════════════╣
║      1 ║          1 ║              1 ║
║      1 ║          1 ║              2 ║
║      1 ║          2 ║              3 ║
╚════════╩════════════╩════════════════╝
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac61d/5)